# disable redirect after add to cart

Tags: cart, routing

How to disable redirect to the cart page when adding a product to cart?

What has to be done so that the user remains on the same page when adding a product to the cart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login into admin and go to

`System` > `Configuration` > `Sales` > `Checkout` >  `After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart` set this option to `No`